# How to build project in unity with custom aspect ratio?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game project that uses a **9:16 aspect ratio**. And also the canvas that will "**Scale with Screen Size**" with "Reference Resolution" **1080x1920 (9:16)**

When I build the project and give some settings in "Player Settings" like this:
[image: Player Settings]

The results of the game are built, always just use "Free Aspect Ratio". 
Like this:

[image: All game components, should be fit with the background]

How can I build a project using only the aspect ratio that I want?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had trouble getting custom aspect ratios in standalone builds as well.

You can set the screen width and height manually once in the start method.

```
void Start()
{
    Screen.SetResolution(1080, 1920);
}
```

If need be, you can also update it while the game is running

```
private float lastWidth;
private float lastHeight;

void Update()
{
    if(lastWidth != Screen.width)
    {
        Screen.SetResolution(Screen.width, Screen.width * (16f / 9f));
    }
    else if(lastHeight != Screen.height)
    {
        Screen.SetResolution(Screen.height * (9f / 16f), Screen.height);
    }

    lastWidth = Screen.width;
    lastHeight = Screen.height;
}
```

Unity Doc:
[Screen](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html)
[SetResolution()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html)

Comment: I have 3 scene in my game. Where should I place this script? (i. e camera.main, etc)

Comment: thank you for your reply. After I created the script for "void Start ()" above. My game can have the resolution that I want, but I tried it from another resolution size of "9:16", which is "360x640" and it works. Thanks

And, I put this script, on every camera playing from all my game scenes.

Note : "Screen.SetResolution" not only has 2 parameters, like the following documentation:https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html

Comment: You're right, `Screen.SetResolution()` has more than 1 overflow method, but you don't need to play with the refresh rate for this example. However, thank you for reminding to include the unity documentation, I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
void Start()
{
    SetRatio(3, 4);
}
void SetRatio(float w, float h)
{
    if ((((float)Screen.width) / ((float)Screen.height)) > w / h)
    {
        Screen.SetResolution((int)(((float)Screen.height) * (w / h)), Screen.height, true);
    }
    else
    {
        Screen.SetResolution(Screen.width, (int)(((float)Screen.width) * (h / w)), true);
    }
}
```